# Why second tk window wont show an image?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.4, tk-toolkit

I get the Lighter image but not the eikona_paixnidiou one. I have even tried not to create a new window but change the existing one but didnt work either. I have also tried Toplevel but didnt work

```
def the_game():
    root=Tk()
    eikona = PhotoImage(file="lighterr.gif") 
    eikona_paixnidiou = Label(master=root,image=eikona)
    eikona_paixnidiou.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=3, columnspan=3)
    root.mainloop()

root=Tk()
photo= PhotoImage(file="anap.gif")
Lighter = Label(master=root,image=photo)
Start=Button(root, text="LET'S START !!!", command= the_game)
Lighter.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=3, columnspan=3)
Start.grid(row=4, columnspan=3)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be just one root window. Use toplevels for all other windows. Only the root window should run `mainloop`. This means that `the_game` should be (with bits to pay attention to indicated):

```
def the_game():
    win = Toplevel(root)
    #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    eikona = PhotoImage(file="lighterr.gif") 
    eikona_paixnidiou = Label(win, image=eikona)
    #                        ^^^^^^
    eikona_paixnidiou.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=3, columnspan=3)
```

The rest of your code looks OK to me.